# ExtJS DataStore - markDirty

Tags: extjs

I'm adding records to a store and marking them dirty using the "markDirty: method on the data record.  Once I have saved the data, I want to mark the records as not dirty anymore.  I checked the documentation and dirty is a readonly field.  I don't see anyway of setting this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Store.commitChanges()` will commit all changes and mark each record as not dirty.  You can also call `commit()` individually on records (or `reject()` to discard changes).

Comment: It sends REST request to server, is there any other way to mark record not dirty without sending request?